# Create a pattern from a list of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sequence

I have a list with elements ranging from 0 -- 3. I want to create a pattern of the list such that if there is a 0, I do not vary any values, if there is a 1 then I vary the values from 0 and 1. If there is a 2, I vary its values from 0, 1 and 2. This may sound confusing, but in a nutshell, I want to generate a pattern like this:

```
input_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
output = [0, 0, 0, 0] # Since input only has 0s we do not permute their values.

input_list = [1,0,0,0]
output = [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0] # We can permute the values of the 1 present.

input_list = [1,0,0,1]
output = [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1]
```

In the case where a list contains 2, we permute its values from 0-1-2

```
input_list = [2,0,0,0]
output = [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [2,0,0,0]

input_list = [1,0,0,2]
output = [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,2], [1,0,0,2]
```

A similar output if there is a 3 present in the list.

I am a bit unsure, about how I should approach this problem. Any help would be great.

P.S. This is not a homework question. I am just working on a research project and need a similar pattern for some simulations. Complexity is not an issue, but would favor a low complexity solution. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
input_list = [1,0,0,2]

list( product(*(range(x+1) for x in input_list)) )
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 2)]
```

Comment: Wait... The trick was to arrange the pattern..? :P This is the easiest solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
input_list = [1, 0, 0, 2]
outputs = []

def get_outputs(input_list):
    if len(input_list) == 0:
        return [[]]
    first = input_list[0]
    outputs = get_outputs(input_list[1:])
    result = [[0] + out for out in outputs]
    if first >= 1:
        result += [[1] + out for out in outputs]
    if first >= 2:
        result += [[2] + out for out in outputs]
    if first == 3:
        result += [[3] + out for out in outputs]
    return result

print(get_outputs(input_list))
```

The solution is NOT optimized. It might take a while to run on big lists. Any improvement or suggestion is highly appreciated.